# Positive edge-triggered JK flip-flop circuit

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop

```
          Next situation
Qc  QB  QA  | Qc  QB  QA   | Jc  Kc  | JB   Kb | JA  Ka
0   0   0   |  0   0   1     0   x     0    x     1  x 
0   0   1   |  0   1   0     0   x     1    x     x  1
0   1   0   |  0   1   1     0   x     x    0     1  x
0   1   1   |  1   0   0     1   x     x    1     x  1 
1   0   0   |  1   0   1     x   0     0    x     1  x
1   0   1   |  1   1   0     x   0     1    x     x  1
1   1   0   |  1   1   1     x   0     x    0     1  x
1   1   1   |  0   0   0     x   1     x    1     x  1
```

I have fill the upper table with using this table   and I did the Jc Kc , JB KB,JA KA

```
Transition   J K
0 0         |0 x
0 1         |1 x
1 0         |x 1
1 1         |x 0
```

is this right as I did? it is for the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0..

Comment: Isn't the next situation at the row for 1 1 0 supposed to be 0 0 0 and not 1 1 1?

Comment: I think no it doesn't want to have 000.

Comment: What jonk is referring to is your last line. **0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0**

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat yes I understand this. On the next situation I must take 1,2,3,4,5,6,0 .You mean on 110 I should have on the next situation 0 0 0 and on the 1 1 1 I must have x x x ?

Comment: If that's what you want.  1 1 1 becomes a don't care state.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I am 100% sure is right my truth table .Are you sure it is right your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you understand, given your earlier comment! That's fantastic. Plus, you've shown your work.

To start, here's the transition table for a JK FF:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Transition} & \text{JK FF} \\\hline
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
\text{start }\to\text{ end}\\\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 0\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c:c}
  J & K \\\\
  0&x\\
  x&0\\
  1&x\\
  x&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

I'm sure we both agree on the above because of the work product I see from you. My table above matches yours. The only differences being that our rows are ordered differently. But they are the same table semantics, regardless.

So, here's your excitation table for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and then back to the start (skipping 7):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{Next State} & \text{Excitations}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}J & K & T & D\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&1&0\\
  \\
  1&1&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}J & K & T & D\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  \\
  x&x&x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K \\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
  \\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
  \\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
  \\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Please note the differences in the above table and see if you follow what I did.

---

Given what I've seen, I think you are quite capable of producing these resulting K-Maps, too:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&0&0&1&0\\
Q_C&x&x&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x\\
Q_C&0&0&x&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&0&1&x&x\\
Q_C&0&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&x&x&1&0\\
Q_C&x&x&x&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&1&x&x&1\\
Q_C&1&x&x&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&x&1&1&x\\
Q_C&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

---

Examination of the above results in:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{JK FF} & \text{Expression}\\\hline
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
  Q_A \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{\overline{Q_B \: Q_C}} J\\
        \vphantom{1} K\end{array}
      \right.\\
  Q_B \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{Q_A} J\\
        \vphantom{Q_A\oplus Q_C} K\end{array}
      \right.\\
  Q_C \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{Q_A\:Q_B} J\\
        \vphantom{Q_B} K\end{array}
      \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
  \left.\begin{array}{c}\overline{Q_B \: Q_C}\\1\end{array}\right.\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}Q_A\\Q_A\,\oplus\, Q_C\end{array}\right.\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}Q_A\:Q_B\\Q_B\end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

---

Which can be implemented this way:

[image]

Comment: my truth table isnt the right ?

Comment: @ek.Nik No, it's not as I see it right now. Compare it with mine. Ask me questions about the differences, if you want. (And if you don't understand my answer, perhaps you shouldn't select it as your answer, yet.)

Comment: I got it.But I don't understand the differences?I mean the  difference between the truth table.

Comment: did I fix it now?

Comment: @ek.Nik Does not look like it to me. Look under your "next situation" column. Do you see it matching mine, exactly???

Comment: I got confused . I see that my next situation with your next state doesn't match. I have got understand it that.I thought that there was an issue on the truth table  there you say Transition with my truth table Transition etc..isn't any issue there?

Comment: Your truth table "Transition" and my "Transition" as I see it are the same so is right ? the other thing about  next situation and next state I got it .I thought it was an issue on that table

Comment: When you are in state 6, you want the ***next*** state to be 0, not 7. But your table shows 7. Also, since state 7 cannot ever occur (it should not be able to), all of its excitations are 'x'. You don't care what happens because the state will never occur. Finally, my column for \$Q_A\$ does not entirely match yours.

Comment: yes man thanks for explain it more but I have got it that.I thought there was an issue with the other table issue

Comment: You mean the JK table I started with? It's the same as yours. No problem there. You nailed that one, just fine. The order of our rows are different. That's all.

Comment: yes thanks for your response man :)

Comment: @ek.Nik Keep up the good work. Just need to practice at it. Not too much. You don't want it to become a grind. You want to enjoy solving problems. But just enough that you feel you can come back to it at a later date and find your way, again. Best wishes!

Comment: you too my man - I hope you all the best

Comment: Dear jonk, I have a question this is syncrhonous right?if it was asynchronous will change ?

Comment: @ek.Nik Synchronous. You can see that the clock hits all of the FFs at the same moment? This isn't a ripple system.

Comment: +1 for the amazingly neat state tables and Karnaugh Maps. It is truly inspiring to see what you can do with MathJax! Please keep it up @jonk .

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the kind comment. A lot can be done, though there are many annoying limitations, too. I wish I had tikz I've needed it many times here.